# Create another java class (POJO )from one java class

Tags: java, xml, pojo

I have one xml file from that I am reading objects using java code.

after reading that object I need to write a code which will create domain file (POJO) class from that objects, so that it will create getter and setter method for the same.

I have written a code which is reading variable and type of the variable from the xml file but I don't know how to create a new java file which will contains that objects and getter setter methods.

here is my code from which I am reading xml.

```
package xmlRead;


import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;  
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;  
import org.w3c.dom.Document;  
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;  
import org.w3c.dom.Node;  
import org.w3c.dom.Element;  
import java.io.File;  

public class ReadXMLFile  
{  
public static void main(String argv[])   
{  
try   
{  
//creating a constructor of file class and parsing an XML file  
String fileName = "C:\\Users\\AcnTUSR\\Downloads\\QiwkIdentityChangeHisotry.qdd";
//File file = new File(fileName);  

File inputHBMFile = new File(fileName);
DocumentBuilderFactory dbInputXMLFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder dInputXMLBuilder = dbInputXMLFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document docInputXML = dInputXMLBuilder.parse(inputHBMFile);
docInputXML.getDocumentElement().normalize();

System.out.println("Root element :" + docInputXML.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());

Element classElementFromInputXML = (Element) docInputXML.getElementsByTagName("class").item(0);
String className = classElementFromInputXML.getAttribute("name");
String tableName = classElementFromInputXML.getAttribute("table");
System.out.println("className::" + className + " -- tableName::" + tableName);

NodeList propNodeList = docInputXML.getElementsByTagName("property");
for (int temp = 0; temp < propNodeList.getLength(); temp++) {
    Node propNode = propNodeList.item(temp);
    System.out.println("\nCurrent Element :" + propNode.getNodeName());
    if (propNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
        String propName = "";
        String propType = "";
        String propLength = "";
        String aliasName = "";

        Element propElement = (Element) propNode;

        propName = propElement.getAttribute("name");
        propType = propElement.getAttribute("type");
        if (propElement.hasAttribute("length")) {
            propLength = propElement.getAttribute("length");
        }
        aliasName = propElement.getAttribute("alias");

        System.out.println("Prop Name::" + propName);
        System.out.println("Prop Type::" + propType);
        System.out.println("Prop Length::" + propLength);
        System.out.println("Prop aliasName::" + aliasName);
    }
}


}   
catch (Exception e)   
{  
e.printStackTrace();  
}  
}  
}
```

can anyone help me with this that how can I create another java file and can create these POJO in that java file?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: What exactly you have trouble with? You don't know how to create file? You don't know syntax for class definition? You don't know syntax for field definition?

Comment: Just output what you gather to a file in java syntax and compile it